# selected change when click on search button

Tags: html, search, select, search-engine, search-box

I created search box with select option, the selected is appear in the top but is change it to the first one in the list when click on search button, how to do that is will not change the selected one ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you add your html & js? a fiddle will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: <form action="file:///C:/Users/jacob/Desktop/WebSearchProject/MainBox2.html" id="cse-search-box">
<input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
<div> 
<input type="text" name="q" id="q" size="65" placeholder="search..." />
<div/>
<select name="cx" id="gh-cat" class="button"> 
<option value="014416480517133683170:dlt3ob9dvi8">in the site</option>
<option value="014416480517133683170:zpyfqpzoski">News</option>
<option value="014416480517133683170:fwigeamu-ai">Shopping</option>
</select>
<button class="button button-red" id="search-button">Search</button>

Comment: see the file with html & js here https://www.transferbigfiles.com/5dcae700-a345-40c4-8194-e71c5144f2fd/mgy_a_UlqB4NcsC0FdM_OA2